# Image inside dialog loads after dialog displays

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify dialog that I am displaying when the page loads, actually a second or so after so that the animation displays to reveal the modal dialog.  The dialog has some text and an image.  Problem is, the dialog displays, then the text pops in and after a delay (while the image downloads) the image then displays and the dialog expands to it's proper size.

How can I get the image to load into memory and be available before the dialog displays?  I want the appearance to be a single smooth transition.  Right now it comes in in chunks.

```
 <template>
    <div>
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" eager persistent max-width="500">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title class="headline green lighten-2 white--text" primary-title>
            <h3>Congratulations!</h3>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>
            <div class="mt-4 mx-0 headline font-italic font-weight-bold green--text">
              You just received a
              <span class="text-no-wrap">pay raise!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-2 mb-3 subtitle-1">Your Pay-Per-Mile has just increased.</div>
            <v-row align="center" justify="center">
              <v-img
                src="@/assets/Thank-you-notes-for-job-well-done.jpg"
                max-height="440"
                max-width="450"
              ></v-img>
            </v-row>
          </v-card-text>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="green" text @click="stop()">Keep it coming</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </div>
  </template>
```

...

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.dialog = true;
  }, 2000);
```

Comment: you might be able to add a hidden `<img>` element with the same src outside of the dialog, so that it is loaded immedately

Comment: @Flame your option works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to have been much easier than I thought.  It felt like the image was defaulting to lazy loading, which apparently it does.  all I had to do was at the eager property to the image and now the image loads as part of the entire dialog.

Comment: I have this problem too, can you show how you fix it?